# Alexa Logging the users utterance

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

im developing an alexa skill with serveral intents. When the user says somethings that doesnt match mythe sample utterances of my intents i want to log that information. This information can be usefull to have a look into what the user says so i can add some intents/utterances to my skill.

I added an AMAZON.FallbackIntent to let the skill answer when the intents/sample utterances dont match BUT
**is there any way to log the utterances of the user?** I cant add slots to the AMAZON.FallbackIntent to catch the value.

Any other ideas?

Comment: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/179174/utterance-accessible-at-the-intent-handler.html :-/

Comment: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/172701/best-practice-for-analytics-logging-of-utterances.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it in the alexa developer console:

- Build tab -> Intent History -> Unresolved Utterances
- more details: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/review-intent-history-devconsole.html

Comment: Yes true but only when u reach 10 users per day :-/

Comment: hehe this is also my issue in most of my skills ;-).